# Can I gulp-concat my system.js angular 1.4 files structure?

Tags: angularjs, concatenation, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I'm following John Papa's structural guidelines for my angular app, so my app has folders for directives, etc. I'm loading them with systemjs, and I'm already minifying/uglyfying them. Is concat'ing them possible with all my requires (which load various resources)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [browserify](http://browserify.org/). It follows your requires at build time, and packages the required stuff into a single file, while wrapping the content of each file in a function to prevent name collisions across files.